# Load and performance test of embedded system

Tags: c, load, arm, embedded-linux, performance-testing

I am adding a new protocol to the existing embedded system on ARM cortex processor. I need to do a load test and performance test after adding the new protocol to earlier system. The source code is in C and C++.

Please let me know if any free test code to do a load and performance test, network I/O test etc on this embedded system. Or suggest me any methods for this.

basically I have to compare:
1. What is the load after adding the new protocol.
2. Performance 
3. Network IO tests
4. System tests 
etc...

Regards,
AK

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For system performance profiling you can use [oprofile](http://oprofile.sourceforge.net/about/) or [gprof](http://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/as/gprof_toc.html).

For network profiling you can use [ethereal](http://www.ethereal.com/) or [netstat](http://linux.die.net/man/8/netstat).

For I/O statistics you can use [iostat](http://linux.die.net/man/1/iostat) or [sar](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sar).

For CPU profiling you can use [mpstat](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/mpstat1.html).

These are only a few tools. I'm sure there are more options available.

Comment: For those following, oprofile and gprof do not appear to be usable on embedded systems and neither site talks about testing embedded systems. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

from google:

For memory leak use  **dmalloc** and **Valgrind**

For tracing use  **LTT (Linux Trace Toolkit)**